# open google play store link of App if a user wants to open website in android phone

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-play

I have a website and an Android application as well. I want my user to be redirected to the Play Store link for my app if they open the website in the Android phone browser. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. When you click on a link to the Play Store from any browser on an Android phone, the Market app will handle the link automatically.

For example, try clicking this link on your Android device:

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps

If the Market app is installed, it will automatically open the page to install the application.

There are lots of resources for detecting an Android user-agent and redirecting. For example http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Redirect to Android-site?
    window.location = 'http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps';
}
```

Comment: i need this to be done onloading of website if browser is of android . it should redirect automatically . i Need to apply a check .

Comment: See updated answer. A quick google search for "redirect mobile users" will turn up lots of options.